# Composer не работает правильно?

Tags: composer, php7, openserver, xampp

В Open Server composer работал правильно. Но появилась необходимость сменить версию php на 7.1.3 т.к. была ошибка при установке проекта. В итоге в настройках осталась версия 7.0

Затем установился Xampp и в браузере в папке проекта в phpinfo версия сменилась
PHP Version 7.3.6
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   C:\WINDOWS
Loaded Configuration File   D:\programms\XAMP\xampp\php\php.ini

Но после команды composer update по прежнему ошибки:

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
>   packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - This package requires php ^7.1.3 but your PHP version (7.0.14) does not satisfy that requirement.   Problem 2
>       - Installation request for doctrine/inflector v1.3.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/inflector[v1.3.0].
>       - doctrine/inflector v1.3.0 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.14) does not satisfy that requirement.   Problem 3
>       - Installation request for laravel/framework v5.7.27 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.7.27].
>       - laravel/framework v5.7.27 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.14) does not satisfy that requirement.   Problem 4
>       - Installation request for laravel/nexmo-notification-channel v1.0.1 -> satisfiable by laravel/nexmo-notification-channel[v1.0.1].
>       - laravel/nexmo-notification-channel v1.0.1 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.14) does not satisfy that requirement.   Problem
>   5
>       - Installation request for laravel/slack-notification-channel v1.0.3 -> satisfiable by laravel/slack-notification-channel[v1.0.3].
>       - laravel/slack-notification-channel v1.0.3 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.14) does not satisfy that requirement.   Problem
>   6
>       - Installation request for laravelcollective/html v5.7.1 -> satisfiable by laravelcollective/html[v5.7.1].
>       - laravelcollective/html v5.7.1 requires php >=7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.14) does not satisfy that requirement.   Problem 7
>       - Installation request for symfony/console v4.2.3 -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v4.2.3].
>       - symfony/console v4.2.3 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.14) does not satisfy that requirement.   Problem 8
>       - Installation request for symfony/contracts v1.0.2 -> satisfiable by symfony/contracts[v1.0.2].
>       - symfony/contracts v1.0.2 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.14) does not satisfy that requirement.   Problem 9
>       - Installation request for symfony/css-selector v4.2.3 -> satisfiable by symfony/css-selector[v4.2.3].
>       - symfony/css-selector v4.2.3 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.14) does not satisfy that requirement.   Problem 10
>       - Installation request for symfony/debug v4.2.3 -> satisfiable by symfony/debug[v4.2.3].
>       - symfony/debug v4.2.3 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.14) does not satisfy that requirement.   Problem 11
>       - Installation request for symfony/event-dispatcher v4.2.3 -> satisfiable by symfony/event-dispatcher[v4.2.3].
>       - symfony/event-dispatcher v4.2.3 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.14) does not satisfy that requirement.   Problem 12
>       - Installation request for symfony/finder v4.2.3 -> satisfiable by symfony/finder[v4.2.3].
>       - symfony/finder v4.2.3 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.14) does not satisfy that requirement.   Problem 13
>       - Installation request for symfony/http-foundation v4.2.3 -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[v4.2.3].
>       - symfony/http-foundation v4.2.3 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.14) does not satisfy that requirement.   Problem 14
>       - Installation request for symfony/http-kernel v4.2.3 -> satisfiable by symfony/http-kernel[v4.2.3].
>       - symfony/http-kernel v4.2.3 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.14) does not satisfy that requirement.   Problem 15
>       - Installation request for symfony/process v4.2.3 -> satisfiable by symfony/process[v4.2.3].
>       - symfony/process v4.2.3 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.14) does not satisfy that requirement.   Problem 16
>       - Installation request for symfony/routing v4.2.3 -> satisfiable by symfony/routing[v4.2.3].
>       - symfony/routing v4.2.3 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.14) does not satisfy that requirement.   Problem 17
>       - Installation request for symfony/translation v4.2.3 -> satisfiable by symfony/translation[v4.2.3].
>       - symfony/translation v4.2.3 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.14) does not satisfy that requirement.   Problem 18
>       - Installation request for symfony/var-dumper v4.2.3 -> satisfiable by symfony/var-dumper[v4.2.3].
>       - symfony/var-dumper v4.2.3 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.14) does not satisfy that requirement.   Problem 19
>       - Installation request for beyondcode/laravel-dump-server 1.2.2 -> satisfiable by beyondcode/laravel-dump-server[1.2.2].
>       - beyondcode/laravel-dump-server 1.2.2 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.14) does not satisfy that requirement.   Problem 20
>       - Installation request for doctrine/instantiator 1.1.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/instantiator[1.1.0].
>       - doctrine/instantiator 1.1.0 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.14) does not satisfy that requirement.   Problem 21
>       - Installation request for myclabs/deep-copy 1.8.1 -> satisfiable by myclabs/deep-copy[1.8.1].
>       - myclabs/deep-copy 1.8.1 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.14) does not satisfy that requirement.   Problem 22
>       - Installation request for nunomaduro/collision v2.1.1 -> satisfiable by nunomaduro/collision[v2.1.1].
>       - nunomaduro/collision v2.1.1 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.14) does not satisfy that requirement.   Problem 23
>       - Installation request for phpunit/php-code-coverage 6.1.4 -> satisfiable by phpunit/php-code-coverage[6.1.4].
>       - phpunit/php-code-coverage 6.1.4 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.14) does not satisfy that requirement.   Problem 24
>       - Installation request for phpunit/php-file-iterator 2.0.2 -> satisfiable by phpunit/php-file-iterator[2.0.2].
>       - phpunit/php-file-iterator 2.0.2 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.14) does not satisfy that requirement.   Problem 25
>       - Installation request for phpunit/php-timer 2.1.1 -> satisfiable by phpunit/php-timer[2.1.1].
>       - phpunit/php-timer 2.1.1 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.14) does not satisfy that requirement.   Problem 26
>       - Installation request for phpunit/php-token-stream 3.0.1 -> satisfiable by phpunit/php-token-stream[3.0.1].
>       - phpunit/php-token-stream 3.0.1 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.14) does not satisfy that requirement.   Problem 27
>       - Installation request for phpunit/phpunit 7.5.6 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[7.5.6].
>       - phpunit/phpunit 7.5.6 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.14) does not satisfy that requirement.   Problem 28
>       - Installation request for sebastian/comparator 3.0.2 -> satisfiable by sebastian/comparator[3.0.2].
>       - sebastian/comparator 3.0.2 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.14) does not satisfy that requirement.   Problem 29
>       - Installation request for sebastian/diff 3.0.2 -> satisfiable by sebastian/diff[3.0.2].
>       - sebastian/diff 3.0.2 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.14) does not satisfy that requirement.   Problem 30
>       - Installation request for sebastian/environment 4.1.0 -> satisfiable by sebastian/environment[4.1.0].
>       - sebastian/environment 4.1.0 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.14) does not satisfy that requirement.   Problem 31
>       - Installation request for sebastian/resource-operations 2.0.1 -> satisfiable by sebastian/resource-operations[2.0.1].
>       - sebastian/resource-operations 2.0.1 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.14) does not satisfy that requirement.   Problem 32
>       - Installation request for symfony/filesystem v4.2.3 -> satisfiable by symfony/filesystem[v4.2.3].
>       - symfony/filesystem v4.2.3 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.14) does not satisfy that requirement.   Problem 33
>       - laravel/framework v5.7.27 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.14) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper v2.5.3 requires illuminate/console ^5.5,<5.8 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.7.27].
>       - Installation request for barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper v2.5.3 -> satisfiable by barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper[v2.5.3].

Comment: Надо сменить версию php.. И вы для этого xampp поставили?

Comment: проверьте PATH - там прописан путь к php версии которая используется по умолчанию. Скорректируйте путь так чтобы он вел к нужной версии

Comment: @Taarim  а где именно этот PATH прописывается?